# Built java project in Netbeans doesn’t include external TEXT files

Tags: java, netbeans

Sorry if the question is basic. I’m trying to build a java project that include **text files** :

```
    File file = new File("data/include/foo.txt");
```

Problem is that with Netbeans, Built and Clean actions are done **without** taking into account external text files.
Can you please help me solving this problem.

Comment: Do you want to include text files in the projects final jar?

Comment: Thank you for question. YES, without these files the application will not process!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netbeans there are basically two types of java projects. One is using **ANT** as its build machine and one is using **maven**.

**Using ANT to build:**

You have to modify or build a `build.xml`. Netbeans offers some targets in its standard `build.xml` to trigger events on each part of the build process.

So to include some additional resource files (in your case some text files) you should add your `build.xml` with a target like

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <jar destfile="dist/myjar.jar" update="true">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
            <include name="data/include/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>
```

It means that after your JAR is build the files from `${basedir}/files/*` are included as well.

**Using MAVEN to build:**

Netbeans uses here completely Mavens infrastructure. So **Maven** does have a standard mechanism to recognize resource files to include. It all comes down to place these files in a specific place of the project. Assuming you did not change this standard directory layout of maven JAR projects is is something like:

```
Project
   src
       main
           java
           resources
   ...
```

So all files placed in `src/main/resources` (including subfolders) are included in your JAR automatically.

Read more [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

**Edit 1:**

To access this resource files you cannot use `File` objects. This is done using the class own getResource methods:

```
App.class.getResourceAsStream("data.xml")

App.class.getResource("data.xml")
```

Here my class is `App` and my datafile is `data.xml` which is in the same directory as my class. This is relative adressed. But if you use a path with a heading `/` then your path is JAR file absolute. Read more about this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for your clear response. I updated Build.xml and as you mentioned a new .jar file including txt files was added but when I execute the main jar file I get an error response indicating that the path was not found (java.io.FileNotFoundException: data\include\file.txt). Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not yet able to vote; vote requires 15 reputations!

Comment: You are right for vote up, which requires 15 points. But you should be able to accept answers.